# Change JSON value in database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a params column in my MySQL database containing this: `'{"usergroup" : "1", "language" : "ENG"}';` . Can I change **only** the language value ENG to GER in just 1 step using a standard PDO update?

Obviously, I could just `SELECT` the whole content of my table cell `'{"usergroup" : "1", "language" : "ENG"}';` , decode it with `json_decode`, change `ENG` to `GER` and `UPDATE` the table cell in a second step.

I'm looking for a shortcut that allows me to `UPDATE` only `ENG` to `GER` without touching the other data or decode/encode the whole data set.

Comment: Why do you have a single column in JSON instead of columns?

Comment: I'm going to add further data to this JSON data set later, so I though it's a more flexible solution than adding more and more columns later on.

Comment: Take a read that [json column vs multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986745/json-column-vs-multiple-columns)

Comment: Interesting read, thank you very much. For my current small project, it doesn't really matter. But for a bigger project, I'm going to use multiple columns instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JSON_REPLACE` function for this.

```
UPDATE `MyTable`
SET `json` = JSON_REPLACE(json, '$.language', 'GER')
WHERE ...
```

Here is an overview of other JSON manipulation functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html.